# Determinant of a $2 \times 2$ block matrix

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, block-matrices

$\textbf{Problem}$: Let a $2n \times 2n$ matrix be given in the form $M=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 
             A & B \\
             C & D \\
                \end{array} } \right]$, where each block is an $n \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $A$ is invertible and that $AC=CA$. Use block multiplication to prove that $\det M= \det(AD-CB)$. Give an example to show that this formula need not hold if $AC \neq CA$

$\textbf{Proof}$: Let $A,B,C,D,X \in \textbf{M}_n(K)$ such that $A+BX$ is invertible.
For all $Y \in \textbf{M}_n(K)$, we have:

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             I_n & 0 \\
             Y & I_n \\
                \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             A & B \\
             C & D \\
                \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             I_n & 0 \\
             X & I_n \\
                \end{array} } \right]= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             A+BX & B \\
             YA+C+(YB+D)X & YB+D \\
                \end{array} } \right].$$

Let $Y=-(C+DX)(A+BX)^{-1}$. Hence:

$$YA+C+(YB+D)X=Y(A+BX)+(C+DX)=0.$$

Since $\det\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             I_n & 0 \\
             Y & I_n \\
                \end{array} } \right]= \det\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             I_n & 0 \\
             X & I_n \\
                \end{array} } \right]= (\det(I_n))^2=1$, we can conclude that:

\begin{align*}
\det\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             A & B \\
             C & D \\
                \end{array} } \right]&=\det\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             A+BX & B \\
             0 & YB+D \\
                \end{array} } \right]\\
&= \det(A+BX)\det(-(C+DX)(A+BX)^{-1}B+D).
\end{align*}

In particular for $X=0$, we have:

\begin{align*}
\det\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             A & B \\
             C & D \\
                \end{array} } \right]&=\det(A)\det(-CA^{-1}B+D)=\det(-ACA^{-1}B+AD) \\
&=\det(-CAA^{-1}B+AD)=\det(AD-CB).
\end{align*}

I just wanted someone to verify my proof and help me with the second part of this question.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Some typesetting advices: `bmatrix` environment is better suited for matrices that `array` (you get nicer code, and need not "predict" the number of columns). Also, [`align*` environment](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Align_%28environment%29) will help you make nice multiline formulas, so they don't "run out" of the post.

Comment: It appears that you could let $X=0$ from beginning to simplify proof.

Comment: See reference to block matrices [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof seems fine to me.

As for a counterexample, consider

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

In one hand, $\det A = -4$ (check [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Det+%7B%7B2%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C2%7D%7D)), and in the other hand, $\det (A_{11} A_{22} - A_{21}A_{12}) = 0$ (check [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Det%28%7B%7B2,0%7D,%7B0,1%7D%7D.%7B%7B1,1%7D,%7B1,2%7D%7D%20-%20%7B%7B2,1%7D,%7B1,1%7D%7D.%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B2,1%7D%7D%29)).